# How to get the average time in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table with sample data  as below

```
ID      History TimeStamp
as45    2020-08-18 13:14:52.697
as45    2020-08-18 13:14:57.857
as45    2020-08-18 13:15:01.667
as45    2020-08-18 13:15:08.450
cpr34   2020-08-18 13:15:13.980
cpr34   2020-08-18 13:15:18.757
cpr34   2020-08-18 13:15:24.163
jk567   2020-08-17 09:40:15.477
jk567   2020-08-17 09:40:19.013
NRM456  2020-08-11 06:26:39.693
NRM456  2020-08-11 06:26:44.613
```

I need to find the average time spent by each ID(ID refers to a user). And I have tried with below query, but giving error.

```
 Select ID,cast(avg(datediff(minute,cast(min([History Timestamp] as datetime),cast(max[History Timestamp] as datetime))) as datetime) as averageTime from *tableName* group by ID
```

But it's not working

Comment: What is the average of a date and time? They aren't numbers. Are you after the mode (the value that appears the most often)?

Comment: Not sure why this was tagged [tag:sql-query-store], a SQL Server feature that seems unrelated to the problem, but please specify the version of SQL Server you need the solution to support.

Comment: Not sure you meant to reopen the question @AaronBertrand ? Though my (lost) close vote was for unclear rather than dupe.

Comment: @Larnu I jumped on the dupe train but then realized that wasn't a duplicate it just sounded similar.

Comment: `Average` has no meaning for dates. A date is just an instant, not a duration. Is something missing from the question perhaps? Is the duration in question the difference between each pair of dates? How could you tell which dates to pair though?  Is each odd date the "start" and the next even date the "end" ? The lack of a clear indicator makes this harder to answer

Comment: The datetime column here logs the various activities (activity column is there in my table) along with  their timestamp of each user which access  a particular application

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the average lag between each successive timestamp (e.g. each timestamp represents time they spent on something since the previous timestamp), and that you're on a modern enough version of SQL Server, given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #x(ID varchar(32), [History Timestamp] datetime);

INSERT #x VALUES
('as45',  '2020-08-18 13:14:52.697'),
('as45',  '2020-08-18 13:14:57.857'),
('as45',  '2020-08-18 13:15:01.667'),
('as45',  '2020-08-18 13:15:08.450'),
('cpr34', '2020-08-18 13:15:13.980'),
('cpr34', '2020-08-18 13:15:18.757'),
('cpr34', '2020-08-18 13:15:24.163'),
('jk567', '2020-08-17 09:40:15.477'),
('jk567', '2020-08-17 09:40:19.013'),
('NRM456','2020-08-11 06:26:39.693'),
('NRM456','2020-08-11 06:26:44.613');
```

You can use [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) to basically self-join between each row and its immediate predecessor, and take the datediff between them:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT ID, 
    cur = [History Timestamp], 
    prev = LAG([History Timestamp], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [History Timestamp])
  FROM #x
)
SELECT 
  ID, 
  Average_Duration_Milliseconds = AVG(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, prev, cur)) 
FROM x 
 GROUP BY ID;
```

Results:

```
ID       Average_Duration_Milliseconds
------   -----------------------------
as45     5251
cpr34    5091
jk567    3537
NRM456   4920
```